# Shimano steps speed sensor testing

Tags: mountain-bike

I am trying to determine if it is in fact the speed sensor on my shimano steps that is causing my E10 error code. Speed sensor is open circuit when magnet not near it and closed when magnet is near it. Does anyone know exactly how this device works and what I should see testing it.

Answer (score 1):

If the sensor is registering consistently as you describe, there's not likely to be anything wrong with it.

E010 appears to be an intermittent power loss error. Start by going through all the physical connections and the battery mount hardware and contacts.

The battery mount hardware in particular is a good place to check first. Basically you're looking for anything that might allow the battery to wiggle and lose contact. Many Steps bikes have a slot type adjustment for the battery mount to fine tune the height/distance so it's snug but not too tight, which allows contact problems if the mount comes loose.